# FreeBSD php files not being read

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I got a little problem with my freebsd apache service.
The problem is that every php file is not being run:

[image: from borwser]

^view from browser

Heres the changes on my httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
<IfModule php5_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<IfModule !php5_module>
<IfModule php4_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<IfModule !php4_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

php.conf:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
<IfModule php4_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
<IfModule php5_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

apache is running:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, except maybe you're missing LoadModule?

Here's mine:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
```

in httpd.conf.  Check the path ... your Apache version may not be 2.4.

```
apachectl configtest
apachectl graceful
```

and I'd think you'd be OK from there!